# Data is not being Stored on Cloud Firestore, although I have written the code to save it but it is not working in my Chat Application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, messenger

[Cloud FireStore ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtmL1.png)

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull; import androidx.annotation.Nullable; import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView; import android.content.Intent; import android.graphics.Bitmap; import android.net.Uri; import android.os.Bundle; import android.provider.MediaStore; import android.view.View; import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.ProgressBar; import android.widget.Toast; import android.widget.Toolbar; import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener; import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener; import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth; import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference; import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore; import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage; import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference; import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask; import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream; import java.io.IOException; import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.Map; public class ControlDesk extends AppCompatActivity {
    //set Profile
    private CardView mgetuserimage;
    private ImageView  mgetuserimageinimageview;
    private static int PICK_IMAGE = 123;
    private Uri imagepath;
    private EditText mgetusername;
    private  android.widget.Button msaveprofile;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private  String name;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private String ImageUriAcessToken;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    ProgressBar mprogressbarofsetprofile;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control_desk);
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference=firebaseStorage.getReference();//it is storage  that redirect
        firebaseFirestore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mgetusername=findViewById(R.id.getusername);
        mgetuserimage=findViewById(R.id.getuserimage);
        mgetuserimageinimageview=findViewById(R.id.getuserimageinimageview);
        msaveprofile=findViewById(R.id.saveProfile);
        mprogressbarofsetprofile=findViewById(R.id.progress_of_set_profile); //////
        mgetuserimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);//to open gallery
               startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);// TO COME BACK TO THE ACTIVITY FROM WHICH IT IS CALLED
            }
        });
        //take code  from image view
        msaveprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                name=mgetusername.getText().toString();
                if(name.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(imagepath==null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    //everthing OK sent data to database
                    mprogressbarofsetprofile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sendDataForNewUser();
                    mprogressbarofsetprofile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(ControlDesk.this,Chat.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //all firebase data come here
    private void sendDataForNewUser(){
        sendDataToRealTimeDatabase();
    }
    private void sendDataToRealTimeDatabase(){
        //sending data to database
        //working with reAl time database we need a class so make class, make userprofile class
        name=mgetusername.getText().toString().trim();//contain name enter by user
        //instance of firebase
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        //take object of database reference
        DatabaseReference  databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());//create reference by name uid , so store data using UID
        userprofile muserprofile=new userprofile(name,firebaseAuth.getUid());//pass 2 things
        databaseReference.setValue(muserprofile);//pass data to data base
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Profile Added Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sendImagetoStorage();//here image not pass to database because user want to see only his image in control desk not all users images, so use sendimagestorage here, when bfor chat activity use database
    }
    private void    sendImagetoStorage() {
        //get acess token of image then sent it to cloud firestore
        //use image compression technique here so that it can be really fast
        StorageReference imageref = storageReference.child("Images").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Profile Pic");// image is the main folder then their are uid of particular images
        //image compression
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imagepath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//inside  bitmap we will have our final image
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();//now array of image is  made , image is now compressed
        //putting image on database storage
        UploadTask uploadTask = imageref.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //now take image url
                imageref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        ImageUriAcessToken = uri.toString();//store image in imageuri acess token
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URI get Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       sendDataTocloudFireStore();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URI FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void sendDataTocloudFireStore() {
        //sending data on cloud firestore we are creating hashmap
        DocumentReference documentReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(firebaseAuth.getUid());//creating document of particular user
        Map<String,Object> userdata=new HashMap<>();//creating map
        userdata.put("name",name);
        userdata.put("image",ImageUriAcessToken);//which will help to retrieve image of user,when i fetch user i also want his image, real time no need
        userdata.put("uid",firebaseAuth.getUid());//compulsory to pass uid
        userdata.put("status","Online");//current status of user when user creating the account or using first time it should be online
        documentReference.set(userdata).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User profile set Sucessfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//on firestore data sent
            }
        });//your choice to add on failure listener
        //if you first login in the app then uninstall then it will rewrite your data for new new data
        //uid is one for one number
    }
    ///to choose image from gallery
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            //requestCode==RESULT_OK //MEANS USER HAS SELECTED AN IMAGE
            imagepath=data.getData(); //Uri of image store here
            mgetuserimageinimageview.setImageURI(imagepath);//show image selecte d by  user
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } }
```

I am getting the issue that data is not being retrieved  in recycler view  from firestore , I realized that data is not being saved in Cloud Firestore  as seen in the screenshot above,Although I have written the code to save data in Cloud FireStore.

```
 UploadTask uploadTask = imageref.putBytes(data);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //now take image url
                imageref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        ImageUriAcessToken = uri.toString();//store image in imageuri acess token
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URI get Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       sendDataTocloudFireStore();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URI FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });


    }

    private void sendDataTocloudFireStore() {
        //sending data on cloud firestore we are creating hashmap
        DocumentReference documentReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(firebaseAuth.getUid());//creating document of particular user
        Map<String,Object> userdata=new HashMap<>();//creating map
        userdata.put("name",name);
        userdata.put("image",ImageUriAcessToken);//which will help to retrieve image of user,when i fetch user i also want his image, real time no need
        userdata.put("uid",firebaseAuth.getUid());//compulsory to pass uid
        userdata.put("status","Online");//current status of user when user creating the account or using first time it should be online

        documentReference.set(userdata).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User profile set Sucessfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//on firestore data sent

            }
        });
```

I think that the problem is that, as in our cloud storage  collection there is no data inside it So kindly help me to find out the error why my data is not being saved in  Cloud firestore.
Kindly check the code and help me.

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages displayed?

Comment: Yes all toast messages are being displayed
URI get success
Login successful
Image uploaded successfully
All toast messages are being displayed and even data is being saved in authentication and real time database also but is not being saved in Cloud Firestore. Kindly help

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to this operation `databaseReference.setValue(muserprofile)`, to see if something's wrong?